# Characteristic function of an integer-valued distribution, inversion formula

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I am working on the following:

> Show that if $\varphi$ the characteristic function of an integer-valued distribution then
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathbb P(X = k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-itk} \varphi(t)\, dt, \quad k \in \mathbb Z.
> \end{align*}

Edit:
It is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ikt} \varphi(t) \, dt 
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ikt} \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{int}p(n) \, dt
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{it(n-k)} p(n) \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{it(n-k)} p(n) \, dt 
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty p(n) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{it(n-k)} \, dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \left(\sum_{n = -\infty}^{k-1} p(n) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{it(n-k)} \, dt + \sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} p(n) \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{it(n-k)} \, dt + 2\pi p(k)\right).
\end{align*}

I'm not sure if the last part is right and I don't know how to go on.

Comment: Note that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{imt}\,dt = \frac{1}{im}\left(e^{im\pi} - e^{-im\pi}\right) = \frac{1}{im}\left((-1)^m - (-1)^{-m}\right) = 0$$ for an integer $m \neq 0$.

Comment: Ah thanks, then I was almost done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can work, we have to use an expression of cumulative distribution function.

There is an approach bases on the expression of the characteristic function: we have $\varphi(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\mathbb P\{X=n\}e^{itn}.$
Since the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\mathbb P\{X=n\}$ is convergent, we can switch the series and the integral.

This has been then tried in the OP: we then use the fact that $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it(n-k)}\mathrm dt=0$ if $n\neq k$ and $2\pi$ if $n=k$.

Comment: But how do we know, that the random variable is discrete?

Comment: Because I thought, that integer valued distribution means the distribution function only takes values in $\mathbb Z$. Is that wrong?

Comment: That correct, I think. And this is what I use.

Comment: Ah thanks, then I was confused by the assignment text.

Comment: But is the statement still correct, if the distribution isn't discrete?

Comment: I've tried what you suggested (see my edit) but in the the end I got 1 instead of $p(k)$. What's wrong now?

Comment: Probably in the indexes: you started with something depending on $k$, then on the RHS you use it as index of summation. It's correct until the end of the second line. Then you get the result.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't matter if I sum over all $k \in \mathbb Z$ or all $n \in \mathbb Z$. But what could I do instead?

Comment: It's a problem if $k$ is supposed to be a fixed integer.

Comment: You're right, I've edited it now.

Comment: I've seen your edit. I included Daniel's comment in the answer.